# I'm getting this error while following reactjs charts-plugin-streaming [UPDATED]

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw4HB.png)
I'm getting - Error: "realtime" is not a registered scale. - when trying to import and use charts-plugin-streaming. I'm using "chartjs-plugin-streaming": "^2.0.0", "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.0", "chart.js": "^3.6.0". [FIXED]
After looking through new migration docs I had fixed the problem, but now it generates a new Error: "TypeError: this._updateScales is not a function. (In 'this._updateScales()', 'this._updateScales' is undefined)"
Here is what I have now:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart as ChartJS } from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-adapter-luxon';
import { StreamingPlugin, RealTimeScale } from 'chartjs-plugin-streaming';

ChartJS.register(StreamingPlugin, RealTimeScale);

const Dashboard = () => {
const data = {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Dataset 1",
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.4,
                backgroundColor: "#f44336",
                borderColor: "#f44336",
                borderJoinStyle: "miter",
                pointRadius: 0,
                showLine: true,
                data: []
            },
        ],
    };

    const options = {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: "realtime",
                realtime: {
                    onRefresh: function (chart) {
                        chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({
                            x: Date.now(),
                            y: Math.random() * 100,
                        });
                    },
                    delay: 300
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container mt-5">
                <h1>Welcome back { name }</h1>
                <div className="column is-half">
                <Line data={data} options={options} width={400} height={200} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `type: "realtime"` doesn't work, because there is no such type. Replace it with a type that actually exists (e.g. "time").

Comment: Sorry not to mention I'm currently using a plugins of chartJS, here is the tutorial link:https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/latest/tutorials/react/stream.html

Comment: In the link, they are not importing RealTimeScale, but they are still using `type: "realtime"`. Have you tried not importing `RealTimeScale`? If so, does it produce the same error, or a different one?